# Класс уничтожается прежде, чем нужно. Как правильно его закрепить?

Tags: c++

Класс уничтожается прежде, чем нужно. 
Как правильно его закрепить в памяти?
Занести его объект в какой либо список?

Comment: Уничтожается кем?

Comment: @Андрей, на класс никто не ссылается, вызывается деструктор класса.

Comment: А как вы хотите воспользоваться этим объектом, если у вас нет на него ссылки?

Comment: @Андрей, нет. Внутри класса в это время запускается отдельный поток и выполняются определенные действия. Эти действия посылают данные в глобальную очередь. А деструктор уничтожает класс, прежде чем данные дойдут (правда через раз)). Как правильно зафиксировать класс в данном случае? p.s. блокировать методы нельзя.

Answer (score 3):

Каково должно быть время жизни этого класса? Если все время работы программы - сделайте его глобальным.

А вообще странный дизайн - поток внутри объекта класса. Логичнее объект класса в потоке создать и работать с ним.

Ну, а выкрутиться - передайте в поток копию и работайте с ней. Если просто копировать нельзя - создавайте свой объект динамически, оберните в `shared_ptr` (если с объектом нужно работать еще и в основной программе) или в `unique_ptr`, который потом передайте в поток...

Answer (score 3):

Без примера кода сложно сказать в чем же ваша проблема. Попробую включить телепатию. Вероятно вы делаете что-то вроде:

```
void foo(){
    MyClass object;
    //...
}
```

И `object` уничтожается при выходе из `foo`.
 В данном случае `object` это стековый объект, который живет ровно до конца текущей области видимости. Если вас не устраивает такое время жизни, то объект нужно создавать в куче и уничтожать вручную:

```
MyClass *object;
void foo(){
    object = new MyClass;
    //...
}
void bar(){
    delete object;
    object = 0; //для порядка
}
```

Однако вам следует быть осторожным, если вы забудете удалить объект, или потеряете указатель на него, то это приведет к утечке памяти.
Немного облегчить жизнь вам могут умные указатели. Например так:

```
std::unique_ptr<MyClass> object;
void foo(){
    object.reset(new MyClass); //Старый объект удален, новый создан
    //...
}
void bar(){
    object.reset(0); //Старый объект удален
}
```

Есть еще вариант, когда объект самоуничтожается выполняя `delete this;`. Однако с этой конструкцией все так просто как может показаться на первый взгляд. Это тема для отдельного вопроса